# Match $and based on array of filter items in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a Collection in MongoDB of `CatalogItems`. Every `CatalogItem` contains a `product` that has an array of `metafields`.

In these metafields there are 2 fields that are `Brand_ID` and `Article_No`

Example CatalogItem document:

```
CatalogItem = {
    product: {
      metafields: [
        {
          key: "Brand_ID",
          value: "317"
        },
        {
          key: "Article_No",
          value: "48630"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I have an array of filters that is used to match the CatalogItems documents based on these metafields

filter array

```
filter = [
    { brandId: '317', articleId: '48630' },
    { brandId: '257', articleId: 'ZSA04036' }
  ]
```

I want to return all CatalogItems that match any of the exact combinations in filter. 
For example to return the stated CatalogItem I currently use this query

```
// Checks for { brandId: '317', articleId: '48630' }
query = {
    $and: [
      { "product.metafields": { $elemMatch: { key: "Brand_ID", value: filter[0].brandId } } },
      { "product.metafields": { $elemMatch: { key: "Article_No", value: filter[0].articleId } } },
    ]
  }
```

The issue that I have is that in order for me to look trough all the filter items I have to increment the filter index and rerunning the query.

For example looking for the second filter index I would have to change
`filter[0].brandId` to `filter[1].brandId`

Is there a way in Mongo to query using a predefined array of objects instead of rerunning the query multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to set variables to the `query` using `$or` and `.forEach()`

```
let query = {
    $or: []
  };
```

```
 filter = [
    { brandId: '317', articleId: '48630' },
    { brandId: '257', articleId: 'ZSA04036' }
  ]

 filter.forEach(filterItem => {
    query.$or.push(
      {
        $and: [
          { "product.metafields": { $elemMatch: { key: "Brand_ID", value: filterItem.brandId } } },
          { "product.metafields": { $elemMatch: { key: "Article_No", value: filterItem.articleId } } },
        ]
      }
    )
  })
```